# Memory not releasing after shutting down vm in Xen-4.5

Tags: memory-management, xen

I installed Xen-4.5.0 on a server with CentOS 6.5(v3.2.30 kernel). All works well except when I shutdown a vm, then xl li shows that the vm's memory is not released and physical memory becomes less and less. What's the reason for this?

Comment: This isnt programming related, you'd probably be better off asking this at [Super user](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The VM's memory goes to memory managed by hypervisor.
You can see it in the `free_memory` field of output of `xl info`.

This memory can be retrieved to the Host/Dom0 by using `xm mem-set` command.

```
[root@hypervisor ~]# xm mem-set
    Error: 'xm mem-set' requires 2 arguments.
    Usage: xm mem-set <Domain> <Mem>
    Set the current memory usage for a domain.
```

Also, please refer http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/memory-not-released-to-dom0-td2598009.html.